# Kusto query to add the names of links clicked, in a separate column

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, click-tracking

The page views are collected in the `pageViews` table and the click responses are stored in the `customEvents` table. I’m trying to get the names of the links clicked on, **per page view**, in a separate column. PFB the webpage code created from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-click-analytics-plugin#snippet-setup-ignore-if-using-npm-setup).

```js
var clickPluginInstance = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ClickAnalyticsPlugin();
var clickPluginConfig = {
  autoCapture: true,
  dataTags: {
    useDefaultContentNameOrId: true
  }
} // Click Analytics configuration
var configObj = {
  instrumentationKey: "<>",
  extensions: [clickPluginInstance],
  extensionConfig: {
    [clickPluginInstance.identifier]: clickPluginConfig
  },
}; // Application Insights Configuration replace instrumentationKey

// Application Insights Snippet code
! function(T, l, y) {
  var S = T.location,
    k = "script",
    D = "ee791e68-981f-468d-947b-eda88f4d79f9",
    C = "https://eastus2-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/",
    I = "disableExceptionTracking",
    E = "ai.device.",
    b = "toLowerCase",
    w = "crossOrigin",
    N = "POST",
    e = "appInsightsSDK",
    t = y.name || "appInsights";
  (y.name || T[e]) && (T[e] = t);
  var n = T[t] || function(d) {
    var g = !1,
      f = !1,
      m = {
        initialize: !0,
        queue: [],
        sv: "5",
        version: 2,
        config: d
      };

    function v(e, t) {
      var n = {},
        a = "Browser";
      return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (m.sv || m.version), {
        time: function() {
          var e = new Date;

          function t(e) {
            var t = "" + e;
            return 1 === t.length && (t = "0" + t), t
          }
          return e.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + t(1 + e.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + t(e.getUTCDate()) + "T" + t(e.getUTCHours()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + ((e.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3) + "").slice(2, 5) + "Z"
        }(),
        iKey: e,
        name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t,
        sampleRate: 100,
        tags: n,
        data: {
          baseData: {
            ver: 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
    var h = d.url || y.src;
    if (h) {
      function a(e) {
        var t, n, a, i, r, o, s, c, u, p, l;
        g = !0, m.queue = [], f || (f = !0, t = h, s = function() {
          var e = {},
            t = d.connectionString;
          if (t)
            for (var n = t.split(";"), a = 0; a < n.length; a++) {
              var i = n[a].split("=");
              2 === i.length && (e[i[0][b]()] = i[1])
            }
          if (!e[C]) {
            var r = e.endpointsuffix,
              o = r ? e.location : null;
            e[C] = "https://" + (o ? o + "." : "") + "dc." + (r || "services.visualstudio.com")
          }
          return e
        }(), c = s[D] || d[D] || "", u = s[C], p = u ? u + "/v2/track" : d.endpointUrl, (l = []).push((n = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", a = t, i = p, (o = (r = v(c, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", o.baseData.exceptions = [{
          typeName: "SDKLoadFailed",
          message: n.replace(/\./g, "-"),
          hasFullStack: !1,
          stack: n + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + a + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + i,
          parsedStack: []
        }], r)), l.push(function(e, t, n, a) {
          var i = v(c, "Message"),
            r = i.data;
          r.baseType = "MessageData";
          var o = r.baseData;
          return o.message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + n + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', o.properties = {
            endpoint: a
          }, i
        }(0, 0, t, p)), function(e, t) {
          if (JSON) {
            var n = T.fetch;
            if (n && !y.useXhr) n(t, {
              method: N,
              body: JSON.stringify(e),
              mode: "cors"
            });
            else if (XMLHttpRequest) {
              var a = new XMLHttpRequest;
              a.open(N, t), a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), a.send(JSON.stringify(e))
            }
          }
        }(l, p))
      }

      function i(e, t) {
        f || setTimeout(function() {
          !t && m.core || a()
        }, 500)
      }
      var e = function() {
        var n = l.createElement(k);
        n.src = h;
        var e = y[w];
        return !e && "" !== e || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = e), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function(e, t) {
          "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t)
        }, n
      }();
      y.ld < 0 ? l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function() {
        l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e)
      }, y.ld || 0)
    }
    try {
      m.cookie = l.cookie
    } catch (p) {}

    function t(e) {
      for (; e.length;) ! function(t) {
        m[t] = function() {
          var e = arguments;
          g || m.queue.push(function() {
            m[t].apply(m, e)
          })
        }
      }(e.pop())
    }
    var n = "track",
      r = "TrackPage",
      o = "TrackEvent";
    t([n + "Event", n + "PageView", n + "Exception", n + "Trace", n + "DependencyData", n + "Metric", n + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + r, "stop" + r, "start" + o, "stop" + o, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), m.SeverityLevel = {
      Verbose: 0,
      Information: 1,
      Warning: 2,
      Error: 3,
      Critical: 4
    };
    var s = (d.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {};
    if (!0 !== d[I] && !0 !== s[I]) {
      var c = "onerror";
      t(["_" + c]);
      var u = T[c];
      T[c] = function(e, t, n, a, i) {
        var r = u && u(e, t, n, a, i);
        return !0 !== r && m["_" + c]({
          message: e,
          url: t,
          lineNumber: n,
          columnNumber: a,
          error: i
        }), r
      }, d.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0
    }
    return m
  }(y.cfg);

  function a() {
    y.onInit && y.onInit(n)
  }(T[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a()
}(window, document, {
  src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",
  crossOrigin: "anonymous",
  cfg: configObj
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ext/ai.clck.2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href="https://google.com" data-custom-id="Google">Google</a> <br>
  <a href="https://youtube.com" data-custom-id="Youtube">Youtube</a> <br>
  <a href="https://spotify.com" data-custom-id="Spotify">Spotify</a> <br>
</body>
```

PFB the attempted query.

```sql
union pageViews, customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(4h)
| project timestamp, client_OS, client_Browser, client_City, operation_Id, name
```

[image: Output Table]

How can one search the `customEvents` table for the same `operation_id` and add a separate column with just the names of all the links clicked?

Comment: Instead of performing union on the tables pageViews ,custom Events try querying the individual table with a specific operationId take a look into those results by applying the filter based on the requirement.

Sample query to work with pageviews
---------------
pageViews
| where operation_Id == "xxx"
------------------

Comment: Here are the list of columns that were supported by [PageViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/pageviews) table , [Custom Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-click-analytics-plugin#custom-event-properties) table

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT, I'm building a click track report. I won't know the `operation_id` of future page views. One needs to `lookup` the `pageview` operation id in `customEvents` and `strcat()` just the names in a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to join the `pageViews` table with the `customEvents` table on `operation_id`, while from the latter you only want to take the list of `name`s.

This should be achieved by two steps:

1. Create a mapping from `operation_id` to the list of `name`s
2. Use `lookup` to join the data from `pageViews` and the mapping from the previous step

This is how you do it (I omitted columns that are not used for the join, just to make the example simpler):

```
// Synthetic data - don't copy this part
let pageViews =
    datatable (timestamp:datetime, operation_Id:string, client_City:string)
        [
            datetime(2022-01-20T06:50:10.343Z), "5cd8b209da4a4062ac11e73a52914e4f", "Chicago"
        ];
let customEvents =
    datatable (timestamp:datetime, operation_Id:string, name:string)
        [
            datetime(2022-01-20T06:50:18.873Z), "5cd8b209da4a4062ac11e73a52914e4f", "Spotify",
            datetime(2022-01-20T06:50:19.928Z), "5cd8b209da4a4062ac11e73a52914e4f", "Youtube"
        ];
// This is the real query
let namesPerOperationId =
    customEvents
    | summarize make_set(name) by operation_Id;
pageViews
| lookup (namesPerOperationId) on operation_Id
```

Result:

| timestamp | operation_Id | client_City | set_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-20 06:50:10.3430000 | 5cd8b209da4a4062ac11e73a52914e4f | Chicago | [ "Spotify", "Youtube" ] |