# Kusto query to add the names of image hyperlinks clicked, in a separate column

Tags: json, azure-application-insights, kql, click-tracking

This is a follow-up with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514456/kusto-query-to-add-the-names-of-links-clicked-in-a-separate-column).

One is able to create a single row of page views and click-tracking details using the `lookup` Kusto operator if the link is a text. However, when the link is an **image**, one needs to use the `customid` attribute and that property is nested within the `customDimensions` property in the `customEvents` table.

```js
var clickPluginInstance = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ClickAnalyticsPlugin();
  var clickPluginConfig = {autoCapture : true, dataTags: {useDefaultContentNameOrId: true}    } // Click Analytics configuration
  var configObj = {instrumentationKey: "<Enter your key>", extensions: [clickPluginInstance],  extensionConfig: { [clickPluginInstance.identifier] : clickPluginConfig },    };  // Application Insights Configuration

 // Application Insights Snippet code
 !function(T,l,y){var S=T.location,k="script",D="ee791e68-981f-468d-947b-eda88f4d79f9",C="https://eastus2-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/",I="disableExceptionTracking",E="ai.device.",b="toLowerCase",w="crossOrigin",N="POST",e="appInsightsSDK",t=y.name||"appInsights";(y.name||T[e])&&(T[e]=t);var n=T[t]||function(d){var g=!1,f=!1,m={initialize:!0,queue:[],sv:"5",version:2,config:d};function v(e,t){var n={},a="Browser";return n[E+"id"]=a[b](),n[E+"type"]=a,n["ai.operation.name"]=S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_",n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"]="javascript:snippet_"+(m.sv||m.version),{time:function(){var e=new Date;function t(e){var t=""+e;return 1===t.length&&(t="0"+t),t}return e.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+t(1+e.getUTCMonth())+"-"+t(e.getUTCDate())+"T"+t(e.getUTCHours())+":"+t(e.getUTCMinutes())+":"+t(e.getUTCSeconds())+"."+((e.getUTCMilliseconds()/1e3).toFixed(3)+"").slice(2,5)+"Z"}(),iKey:e,name:"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights."+e.replace(/-/g,"")+"."+t,sampleRate:100,tags:n,data:{baseData:{ver:2}}}}var h=d.url||y.src;if(h){function a(e){var t,n,a,i,r,o,s,c,u,p,l;g=!0,m.queue=[],f||(f=!0,t=h,s=function(){var e={},t=d.connectionString;if(t)for(var n=t.split(";"),a=0;a<n.length;a++){var i=n[a].split("=");2===i.length&&(e[i[0][b]()]=i[1])}if(!e[C]){var r=e.endpointsuffix,o=r?e.location:null;e[C]="https://"+(o?o+".":"")+"dc."+(r||"services.visualstudio.com")}return e}(),c=s[D]||d[D]||"",u=s[C],p=u?u+"/v2/track":d.endpointUrl,(l=[]).push((n="SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)",a=t,i=p,(o=(r=v(c,"Exception")).data).baseType="ExceptionData",o.baseData.exceptions=[{typeName:"SDKLoadFailed",message:n.replace(/\./g,"-"),hasFullStack:!1,stack:n+"\nSnippet failed to load ["+a+"] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: "+(S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_")+"\nEndpoint: "+i,parsedStack:[]}],r)),l.push(function(e,t,n,a){var i=v(c,"Message"),r=i.data;r.baseType="MessageData";var o=r.baseData;return o.message='AI (Internal): 99 message:"'+("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) ("+n+")").replace(/\"/g,"")+'"',o.properties={endpoint:a},i}(0,0,t,p)),function(e,t){if(JSON){var n=T.fetch;if(n&&!y.useXhr)n(t,{method:N,body:JSON.stringify(e),mode:"cors"});else if(XMLHttpRequest){var a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open(N,t),a.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json"),a.send(JSON.stringify(e))}}}(l,p))}function i(e,t){f||setTimeout(function(){!t&&m.core||a()},500)}var e=function(){var n=l.createElement(k);n.src=h;var e=y[w];return!e&&""!==e||"undefined"==n[w]||(n[w]=e),n.onload=i,n.onerror=a,n.onreadystatechange=function(e,t){"loaded"!==n.readyState&&"complete"!==n.readyState||i(0,t)},n}();y.ld<0?l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e):setTimeout(function(){l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e)},y.ld||0)}try{m.cookie=l.cookie}catch(p){}function t(e){for(;e.length;)!function(t){m[t]=function(){var e=arguments;g||m.queue.push(function(){m[t].apply(m,e)})}}(e.pop())}var n="track",r="TrackPage",o="TrackEvent";t([n+"Event",n+"PageView",n+"Exception",n+"Trace",n+"DependencyData",n+"Metric",n+"PageViewPerformance","start"+r,"stop"+r,"start"+o,"stop"+o,"addTelemetryInitializer","setAuthenticatedUserContext","clearAuthenticatedUserContext","flush"]),m.SeverityLevel={Verbose:0,Information:1,Warning:2,Error:3,Critical:4};var s=(d.extensionConfig||{}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics||{};if(!0!==d[I]&&!0!==s[I]){var c="onerror";t(["_"+c]);var u=T[c];T[c]=function(e,t,n,a,i){var r=u&&u(e,t,n,a,i);return!0!==r&&m["_"+c]({message:e,url:t,lineNumber:n,columnNumber:a,error:i}),r},d.autoExceptionInstrumented=!0}return m}(y.cfg);function a(){y.onInit&&y.onInit(n)}(T[t]=n).queue&&0===n.queue.length?(n.queue.push(a),n.trackPageView({})):a()}(window,document,{
    src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    cfg: configObj
  });
```

```css
svg{width: 40px;height: 40px;  border-radius: 35px; padding: 5px; border-color: currentColor;border-style: dashed;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ext/ai.clck.2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href = https://www.facebook.com data-customid = FB>       <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">   <use href=#Facebook></use></svg></a>
  <a href = http://www.linkedin.com  data-customid = Linkedin> <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">   <use href= #LinkedIN></use></svg></a>
</body>

<svg style="display: none">
  <symbol id= Facebook>  <text x=4 y=14 font-size=16 font-family=Tahoma font-weight=bold >f </text> </symbol>
  <symbol id= LinkedIN>  <text x=1 y=13 font-size=16 font-family=Myriad font-weight=bold >in</text> </symbol>
</svg>
```

[image]

How should one create a `set` for the names of the URL in this scenario and look up the `operation_Id` in the `pageviews` table? PFB the mock data for both tables in such a scenario.

```
let customEvents =
datatable (timestamp:datetime, name:string, operation_Id:string, customDimensions:dynamic)[
        datetime(2022-01-23T19:50:33.481Z), 'not_specified', "849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627", dynamic({"baseTypeSource":"ClickEvent","clickCoordinates":"25X24","content":{"customid":"FB","contentName":" "}}),
        datetime(2022-01-23T19:50:35.225Z), 'not_specified', "849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627", dynamic({"baseTypeSource":"ClickEvent","clickCoordinates":"37X86","content":{"customid":"Linkedin","contentName":" "}})
    ];
customEvents        


let pageViews = datatable (timestamp:datetime, operation_Id:string, client_City:string)
[ datetime(2022-01-23T19:49:42.075Z), "849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627", "Chicago"]; 
pageViews
```

PFB expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to extract the correct field from a dynamic value. This is achieved this way: `tostring(customDimensions.content.customid)`. So your final query will look like this:

```
// Synthetic data - don't copy this part
let customEvents =
    datatable (timestamp:datetime, name:string, operation_Id:string, customDimensions:dynamic)[
        datetime(2022-01-23T19:50:33.481Z), 'not_specified', "849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627", dynamic({"baseTypeSource":"ClickEvent","clickCoordinates":"25X24","content":{"customid":"FB","contentName":" "}}),
        datetime(2022-01-23T19:50:35.225Z), 'not_specified', "849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627", dynamic({"baseTypeSource":"ClickEvent","clickCoordinates":"37X86","content":{"customid":"Linkedin","contentName":" "}})
    ];
let pageViews =
    datatable (timestamp:datetime, operation_Id:string, client_City:string) [
        datetime(2022-01-23T19:49:42.075Z), "849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627", "Chicago"
    ];
// This is the real query
let namesPerOperationId =
    customEvents
    | extend customDimensions = tostring(customDimensions.content.customid)
    | summarize make_set(customDimensions) by operation_Id;
pageViews
| lookup (namesPerOperationId) on operation_Id
```

Result:

| timestamp | operation_Id | client_City | set_customDimensions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-23 19:49:42.0750000 | 849c4fde676a4cb691d95daa763ed627 | Chicago | [ "FB", "Linkedin" ] |

Answer (score 2):

You can create the set like this:

```
let namesPerOperationId =
    customEvents
    | summarize make_set(customDimensions.content.customid) by operation_Id;
```